# Is "check it out again" correct? How can this be simpler?

Tags: difference

I encountered this sentence then I confused about sentence structure, I know the `Y` example is incorrect, but I don't know why? (*The problem is I don't know exactly what I must look for about this grammar*).

X- **check it out again.**

Y- **check out it again.**

and the second question, how can we write this sentence simpler?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb in this example is `to check out [object]` (definition 4 at [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/check_out)). When the object is a pronoun only, the pronoun is inserted after "check:" `to check it out`, `to check this out`. You could say "Check out this book," but not "Check out this." You would never say "Check out it."

More context is needed to answer your second question but I don't think it is a complicated phrase that needs to be simplified.

Comment: Saying **Check out this** is fine (at least in my dialect).  It does have a sense of emphasizing the **this**, like '"Check out **this**," said Peter, tossing the magazine with his face on the cover onto the table.'